# Charity donations

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

I just spent about an hour researching the answer to what seemed to be a simple question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62329645/61311

I'm not really interested in StackOverflow reputation points etc, I do this because I want to help people - but what would be really nice would be if me helping someone encouraged that person to help my favourite charity, even as a one-off.

So, I have two questions:

1. What do the SO people think of allowing users to specify a charity from a predefined list. The selected charity would be shown somewhere near the answer so people can donate if they wish (no pressure). The list would be predefined to stop people collecting for themselves, so charities like Cancer Research, Doctors Without Borders, etc.
2. Would it be objectionable for me to include a signature in each of my answers linking to https://msf.org.uk/donate

Thanks

Comment: Signatures are generally frowned upon, as is anything that isn't related to the question. If you want to put a link to a donation page, I think your user profile would be the proper place for it.

Comment: I don't think a list of charities near an answer is a good idea. However, do note that SE itself donates $100 to a charity of your choice every year, for the low, low price of becoming a moderator and investing countless hours into moderating SE sites (for example, [2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/09/stack-gives-back-2019/))

Comment: @ErikA The list wouldn't be near the answer. Only a single one would be near the answer - the one in the profile of the person who answered.

Comment: Does down-voting on `meta` mean that people don't want it, or that the post is poorly written / inappropriate etc?

Comment: It can mean either of both, but in this case it's likely disagreement. Downvotes here don't affect reputation nor your ability to ask future questions, so don't worry about it

Comment: While I truly appreciate your altruism and your intent - this just would never work for what  SO and the network is/how it works. You're more than free to put whatever you want (within rational reason in your user profile that's not offensive etc...) but you'd have to leave it at that. For instance, some people put in a link to their Amazon wish list, and I'm sure I've seen some before that have said, "if you think my answer really helped you out of a whole - consider spending the cost of a cup of a coffee for XYZ charity"...

Comment: ...so you're more than free to do that, and if someone checks out your profile after you've helped them and sees it, agrees with your chosen cause etc..., and is feeling generous that if they wish to pull out their wallet/purse/whatever, then so be it. But as mentioned in comments above, and indeed in EJoshuaS' answer - it'd come out as either demanding, setting an onus of people that if they ask a question that gets an answer they have to donate "something" (guilt tripping them maybe), and that not how things work when sharing knowledge...

Comment: ... so to sum up, it's great you feel passionate for a cause - and please keep going for it - as we need it in these crazy times, but please don't add a link to your answers to try and get that done - it'll come across as understood but get removed eventually and might even get you considered if you keep linking stuff to the same site thought a spammer (despite best intentions). No one wants that and no one benefits from it... just put it in your profile and if someone happens across it - that's the best you can do here. Best of luck.

Comment: I agree with you 99%. If the link is in the answer then it looks like you are demanding payment because you have added it individually. However, if a small icon is displayed beneath the "Accepted answer" tick, or as part of the user info then that is in a non-editable part of the site, and therefore is psychologically different. In fact, adding it to the user info is great, because it's about the poster, not the answer.

Comment: *Does down-voting on meta mean that people don't want it, or that the post is poorly written / inappropriate etc?* In my case, my downvote was merely signaling disagreement (because it seems like it's an implied request for payment for the answer, which I don't agree with).

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica If the link were in an area such as the poster's info then it wouldn't be an implied request for payment for the answer (because it wasn't entered for that specific answer). But it's not going to happen, so we don't really need to reach an agreement on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applaud you for thinking like this!

I think there’s already a solution for this though: your profile. I have seen several people with *personal* tip jar links (eg to Ko-fi) here so this would definitely be within what we allow in profiles.

(Note: Questions, answers and comments are for Q&A, so it would not be accepted to put the link there.)

Answer (score 14):

Stack Exchange sites are free. As soon as you have something like that, it essentially becomes an implied request for a payment for the answer. I'm not comfortable asking people for that (even if it's indirect payment via donation to a charity).

Personally, the main payment I receive for answering and site curation is the fact that I get others to help me by posting my questions, and I get information from other people's answers.

Comment: A link in the answer would, but I don't think having a small logo alongside the user's info would because it's compartmentalised into an "about the user" section.